# JQuery addEventListener not resetting after keydown input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create an event listener that listens for the keyboard input `ZZPX` and focuses a text input - so that when a barcode is scanned e.g. ZZPX12345 the 12345 portion is entered into a text input and the form is submitted.

Everything works fine except once ZZPX has been entered the script keeps looping so if any other keys are pressed it automatically focuses the text input for ANY key. I assume I need to try and reset this listener but I'm not sure how to and I've tried looking at other methods but to no avail.

```
if ( window.addEventListener ) {
    var kkeys = [], konami = "90,90,80,88"; 
    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
            kkeys.push( e.keyCode );
            if ( kkeys.toString().indexOf( konami ) >= 0 ) {
                // run code here    
                $("#barcodeInput").focus();
            }
    }, true);
}
```

Comment: Your issue is not about jQuery. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `removeEventListener`. You also need to wrap the event handler into a separate function for readability.

```js
if ( window.addEventListener ) {
    var kkeys = [], konami = "90,90,80,88"; 
    window.addEventListener("keydown", window_keyDown, true);   
}

var kkeys = [], konami = "90,90,80,88"; 
function window_keyDown(evt) { 
    kkeys.push( evt.keyCode );
    if ( kkeys.toString().indexOf( konami ) >= 0 ) {
        // run code here
        $("#barcodeInput").focus();
        window.removeEventListener("keydown", window_keyDown);
    } 
}
```

If for some reason you do not want to seperate the function, you can use the following:

`window.removeEventListener("keydown");`

instead of

`window.removeEventListener("keydown", window_keyDown);`